# Ошибка сборки Pug в Webpack при работе cо свойством srcset

Tags: webpack, pug

Использую шаблонизатор Pug. Для Webpack применяю pug-loader. Подключаю его в webpack.config.js:

```
        {
            test: /\.pug$/,
            loader: "pug-loader",
        },
```

При обработке синтаксиса для описания плотности экрана в изображении (речь про идентификаторы: 1x, 2x, 3x):

```
img(srcset=require("../images/image.webp 1x, ../images/image.webp@2x 2x") type="image/webp")
```

получаю ошибку сборки:

```
ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
```

То есть ошибка возникает из-за того, что атрибут srcset содержит не просто URL-адрес, а несколько строк, разделённых запятыми. Но это всего лишь стандартный синтаксис этого свойства в html. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с этой ситуацией. Буду благодарен за совет. Спасибо.